# fade out div after x seconds with jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, delay

I do a fade in div that is not displayed when I load the page:

```
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#box').fadeIn('slow');
```

I would do this instructions after x seconds, doing a fadeOut of the div:

```
$('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
$('#box').hide();
```

How can I do it?
Actually fadeOut is done on button click.

The script is here: http://clouderize.it/cookie-localstorage/a.php 
The div that appear when I click on another image will disappear after x seconds.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [`.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method is purpose built for what you are describing:

```
$('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
$('#box').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).hide(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could use `setTimeout()`

```
var xSeconds = 1000; // 1 second

setTimeout(function() {
   $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
   $('#box').hide();
}, xSeconds);
```

Comment: @michele Could you please describe what goes wrong? This approach can be seen working here: http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too late to reply but I found a way which helped me.

$("#overlay").fadeTo(10000,1).fadeOut(5000);

Refer this link
http://juristr.com/blog/2009/12/howto-fade-out-div-after-some-seconds/

It allows you to set a time like when you want the div to disappear and with what speed.