# jQuery fade-out DIV display after certain set time

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and would like to hide a DIV (`.video-field-new`) after a specified amount of time after the page loads, for example 5 seconds. Is that possible?

```
<div id="BodyField">
    <div class="video-field-new"></div>
</div>
```

And bonus if I could have it fade-out instead of just disappearing as the user will see this occurring.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Did you try something ? What ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fade out div after x seconds with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425347/fade-out-div-after-x-seconds-with-jquery)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ $('.video-field-new').fadeOut() }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Although Starx answer is short and readable, it doesn't specifically pay regard to the "page load" that the OP asked for so +1 for both answers.

Answer (score 46):

You can do it in this way

```
$("#BodyField").delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: pretty clean solution. I like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#div').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
$('#div-inner').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).hide(0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even We can do like this:
in html

```
    <div id="BodyField">
        <div class="video-field-new">
      <p>This is your DIV with text which will fade Out after delay 5s using jQuery</p>
      <p>This is your DIV with text which will fade Out after delay 5s using jQuery</p>
      <p>This is your DIV with text which will fade Out after delay 5s using jQuery</p>
      <p>This is your DIV with text which will fade Out after delay 5s using jQuery</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

in js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.video-field-new').delay(5000).show().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

in css:

```
div { 
    width:200px; 
    height:80px; 
    float:left; }
```

For Demo Click on Link 
https://jsfiddle.net/kingtaherkings/133v70se/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.video-field-new').fadeOut(5000)
})
```

`$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)`

**Parameter**                  |              **Description**

---

**speed** =    Optional. Specifies the speed of the fading effect. Default value
is 400 milliseconds

Possible values:

- milliseconds
- "slow"
- "fast"

---

**easing** =   Optional. Specifies the speed of the element in different points of
the animation. Default value is "swing"

Possible values:

- "swing" - moves slower at the beginning/end, but faster in the middle
- "linear" - moves in a constant speed

---

**callback** =     Optional. A function to be executed after the fadeOut()
method is completed

---

for more information check this doc https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp